"Could not load source layer for INPUT'" when running Smooth to make kernel density estimate heatmap in QGIS
How to make a KDE map when it keeps giving me this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.12\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\gdal_argparse.py", line 229, in main 
self.doit(**kwargs) 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.12\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 355, in doit 
return gdal_polygonize(**kwargs) 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.12\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\auxiliary\util.py", line 62, in enable_exceptions_wrapper 
return fun(*args, **kwargs) 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.12\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_polygonize.py", line 149, in gdal_polygonize 
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource(dst_filename) 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.12\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 723, in CreateDataSource 
return _ogr.Driver_CreateDataSource(self, *args, **kwargs) 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
RuntimeError: ILI2 Create(): model file not specified in destination filename.
Process returned error code 1
Results:
{OUTPUT:'C:/Users/(my_name)/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YHfJFg/7d2467b56a874980bf668f9c7e6bf9de/OUTPUT.xtf' }
OK. Execution took 1.731 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: native:smoothgeometry_1
Running Smooth [23/23]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'C:/Users/my_name/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YHfJFg/7d2467b56a874980bf668f9c7e6bf9de/OUTPUT.xtf', ITERATIONS: 3, MAX_ANGLE: 180, OFFSET: 0.5, OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/my_name/Documents/homerangevector.gpkg' }
Error encountered while running Smooth: Could not load source layer for INPUT: C:/Users/my_name/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YHfJFg/7d2467b56a874980bf668f9c7e6bf9de/OUTPUT.xtf not found
Execution failed after 98.65 seconds (1 minute 39 seconds)

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Home Range KDE' finished



Which QGIS version is it? Try to use the LTR

QGIS 3.34 prizren long term release

The Long Term Release is exactly QGIS 3.34

Is it possible for you to share your data with us for testing purposes?

how would i do that?

try via an online sharing platform or drive

sure, i can WeTransfer the files to you, do you have an email address i can send them to?

Just share the link here

https://datarepository.movebank.org/entities/datapackage/d4074e60-62e1-419c-8dc6-ab37ff9ba999

its the reindeer movement in east iceland csv file and then the Heida reindeer data from there
